# (Spring-boot & Spring data jpa) How to change the datasource on the fly?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, datasource, spring-data-jpa

For my new project, I built a basic rest api to return data at the client request. However, the client must select the databse of his choice, as a parameter of the HTTP GET request.

Now my question is that I don't know how to do that with Sprint-boot. I know that we can provide many different datasources, but how can we change the desired datasource after inspecting the request ?

Here is my data sources config, which works well :

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.dev21")
    public DataSource dev21DataSource() throws SQLException {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.dev22")
    public DataSource dev22DataSource() throws SQLException {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

If I want to switch between dev21 and dev22 dynamically, what should I do ? 
I have read articles about the class **AbstractRoutingDataSource**, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Please have a look here: [Dynamic database connection switching and application multitenancy with database routing](http://springrules.blogspot.com/2017/08/dynamic-database-connection-switching.html)

Answer (score 0):

Without having tested it, and only looking briefly through the javadoc, something like this might work

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    public DataSource dev21DataSource() throws SQLException {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    public DataSource dev22DataSource() throws SQLException {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        RoutingDataSource ds = new RoutingDataSource();

        DataSource ds21 = dev21DataSource();
        DataSource ds22 = dev22DataSource();

        Map dataSources = new HashMap();
        dataSources.put(1, ds21);
        dataSources.put(2, ds22);

        ds.setDefaultTargetDataSource(ds21);
        ds.setTargetDataSources(dataSources);

        return ds;
    }
}

public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        if (true) { //Should probably be some thread/tracaction/request safe check
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

You might want to `override` other method if you need other behavior from the class.

Answer (score 0):

It should go along the lines of this:

```
// create class to hold the "key" to choose your datasource
// you will determine it from your GET or POST request
// It uses ThreadLocal so you will get one per each request
public class SomeRequestContext {
    private static ThreadLocal<Object> keyToChoseDataSource = new ThreadLocal<>();
    public static void setKeyToChoseDataSource(Object key) {
        keyToChoseDataSource.set(key);
    }
    public static Object getKeyToChoseDataSource() {
        return keyToChoseDataSource.get();
    }
}

// This is you AbstractRoutingDataSource implementation that will
// get the key out of the context class above
public class MultiDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return SomeRequestContext.getKeyToChoseDataSource();
    }
}
```

And in your configuration:

```
    // Here you just put all your data sources into the AbstractRoutingDataSource implementation
    @Bean 
    @Primary 
    public DataSource dataSource() {
      MultiDataSource dataSource = new MultiDataSource();
      dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(someDefaultDataSource());
      Map<Object,DataSource> resolvedDataSources = new HashMap<Object,DataSource>();
      resolvedDataSources.put("dev21",buildDataSource21());
      resolvedDataSources.put("dev22",buildDataSource22());
      // ...etc...
      dataSource.setTargetDataSources(resolvedDataSources);
      dataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
      return dataSource;
    }
```

And in your controller

```
@Controller
public class YourController {
    @Autowired
    private YourRepository yourRepository;
    @RequestMapping(path = "/path", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> createStuff() {
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(tenantName);
        SomeRequestContext.setKeyToChoseDataSource(getKeyFromRequest()); // this will be dev21 or dev22 or whatever

        SomeStuff stuff = new SomeStuff();
        yourRepository.save(stuff); // will be saved to the correct database
        return ResponseEntity.ok(stuff);
    }
}
```